# Can't store a boolean returned by a function in a variable in typescript

Tags: typescript

Please anyone tell me how to  store a boolean returned by a function in a variable.

```
var output=this.loginService.IsLogin(Username, Password).subscribe();

var output=this.loginService.IsLogin(Username, Password).subscribe();

if (output == true) {
  this.router.navigate(['/incidentSupport'])
}
else if (userName.trim() == "" && password.trim() == "")
{
  this.msg = "Please enter the username or Password"
}
else
{
  this.msg = "Invalid username or password"
}
```

I am expecting value should store bolean value either true or false in variable

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Service which I assume is calling RXJS so your `IsLogin` Function looks something like this?

```
IsLogin(start: string, end: string): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.get(URL)
}
```

If yes you are returning an Observable which is asynchron as it's a request to a server and thus has latency (Not just that, this is just a really quick n'dirty explanation).

So How do you solve that problem? `subscribe` accept a callback and passes the retrieved value as argument. This is how I would go about it:

```
this.loginService.IsLogin(Username, Password).subscribe((resp: any) => {
  // This assumes that your API directly returns a boolean
  if(output) {
    this.router.navigate(['/incidentSupport']);
  }
  else if(userName.trim() == "" && password.trim() == "") {
    this.msg = "Please enter the username or Password"
  }
  else {
    this.msg = "Invalid username or password"
  }
});
```